# How to play WebRTC media stream on Safari and iOS 11

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

Apple purports to support WebRTC as of iOS 11 and the new desktop Safari. However, the number of lockouts on media playing make me question if "WebRTC" is really supported.

My application previously worked on these devices. Now it does not.

Code, works elsewhere:

```
GlobalRTCObject.onaddstream = function(event){
    Player.srcObject = event.stream;
    Player.play();
};
```

Error message from the Apples:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

What is the Apple approved way to receive stream? The user has already clicked all sorts of buttons to get to this point. It's really quite ridiculous that Apple keeps breaking these apps to protect people from theirself--there's a back button and a red X to leave unwanted pages that play sound.

Also, assuming there is a fix, is there a property stored in the browser for "feature" support of "lock down everything so stuff doesn't work"? I don't want all of my users to have to click 100 buttons to get things to work, but I'd rather do a feature detection a bit more accurate than just user agent.

An ideal fix would work for media streams that might be added in the future without user input. Some events have not year occurred in time. Think things like weather alerts or live TV events. A user should be able to stay on a page that plays these things when they finally exist.

Comment: I should add for clarity that `Player` is a html5 audio tag.

Comment: Nice to "meet" you again ;-) WebRTC **is** really supported by Apple. Do you use the [latest adapter](https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js)? To test I used [codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/webrtc-web) from Google, that works fine with some exceptions. See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462247/webrtc-most-of-the-times-connecting-safari-with-chrome-is-not-working) for these exceptions. At least safari-safari works in all cases for me. Hope I help you with this info !!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far, but I will not mark this as correct because it is involving too much user intervention.

This catches the Apple media lockout promise rejection error on `html5audio.play()` and gives the user something to click on, even though they really don't want to click again and just want to hear their stream once it connects. They are really tired of clicking because they've had to click a lot, including to allow microphone access so ICE candidates will be provided even though it is a one way stream. Really poor user experience, and I will literally cry if Apple breaks this again after reading this post.

```
<script>
// Play audio stream once it arrives
    GlobalRTCObject.onaddstream = function(event){
    Player.srcObject = event.stream;
    var AppleHack = Player.play();

    if (AppleHack !== undefined){

    AppleHack.catch(function(error){

    document.getElementById("UserControl").innerHTML = '<div id="StartPlaying">Play</div>';
    document.getElementById("StartPlaying").addEventListener("click", StartPlaying, true);
    }).then(function(){
    // If you want to do something every time it starts playing
    }); 
    }
};
</script>
```

This is based off of something I found online awhile back about iOS 11.

I also have a big red blob of text explaining things so the user realizes they need to click more things.

I've found the native HTML5 audio controls are not always reliable at starting it. Even more interesting, if you play/pause cycle the native controls, it usually raises the volume level substantially, which is good, because before it was way too soft to be useful without amplified headphones.

I hope this helps someone else, but I still hope for a better solution.